# Is there an 'upload a file' option?

Tags: discussion, support

I've posted a question regarding Windows NTLM authentication. One of the serverfault members asked me if I can upload a *.pcap file with the NTLM authentication process. 
So the question is can I upload simple configuration files or dump files (like *.pcap files) on ServerFault? If not, can I paste links to externally hosted files?
Do you plan to add an option to upload files in the future?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't. You can use something like pastebin on inline the snippet in a code block if it's not too big.

Answer (score 3):

You can only upload image files unfortunately, so if you want to host some non-text data, you'll need to post it somewhere else.

As MDMarra said, pastebin is good if you have a huge text file (such as an installation log) that's too big for thr question.

Answer (score 2):

Being the one who asked for the capture, I'll chime in..

All of the conversation of the NTLM auth process is in HTTP headers; the full packet capture is unnecessary (and probably exposes more data about your network than you'd like to have out on the internet).

In Wireshark, you can review just the content of the stream by right-clicking on one of the packets and selecting "Follow TCP Stream"; this should contain all of the relevant traffic in plain text.